# Mysql query crashes whole site

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
orders.c5_dataset,
orders.orders_id,
orders_products.products_id,
orders_products.products_name,
IFNULL(Sum(orders_products.products_quantity), 0) AS count,
p.product_certain_amount,
p.product_stock_amount,
p.product_group_number,
p.products_status,
p.products_competitor_watch,
p.product_reseller_account_no,
competitor_prices.competitor_prices_price
FROM
orders
LEFT JOIN
orders_total ON orders_total.orders_id = orders.orders_id
LEFT JOIN
orders_products ON orders_products.orders_id = orders.orders_id
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT products.products_id, products.product_reseller_account_no, 
products.product_certain_amount, products.product_stock_amount, 
products.product_group_number, products.products_status, 
products.products_competitor_watch, products.manufacturers_id FROM products 
GROUP BY products.products_id) p ON orders_products.products_id = 
p.products_id
LEFT JOIN
competitor_prices ON competitor_prices.products_id = p.products_id
WHERE
orders_total.class = 'ot_total'
AND
orders.date_purchased > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL '$days' DAY)
GROUP BY
orders_products.products_id
ORDER BY
count DESC
```

I've got this query and it crashes the whole site because of the joined subquery..

I can't quite figure out what's wrong.

I suspect it might be something with the product query. It's a subquery since some of the tables have the same fields and the count-part of the select ends up wrong without it.

Comment: whats the relevance of $leftjoin

Comment: Is it giving you any error messages? Because it should. This _(SELECT products.products_id, products.product_reseller_account_no, products.product_certain_amount, products.product_stock_amount, products.product_group_number, products.products_status, products.products_competitor_watch, products.manufacturers_id FROM products GROUP BY products.products_id)_ is not correct syntax. You have a GROUP BY and lots of non-aggregate attributes that aren't in the GROUP BY in the select.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Nothing, actually. Just forgot to remove it before posting :-)

Comment: possibly the reason its crashing?

Comment: @Magisch Nope, no errors. Just a massive crash of the entire thing. Running MySQL with PHP 5.2, if that's any help.

Comment: Similarly for the whole thing. Everything you select in a query with GROUP BY must either be part of what is being grouped by or an aggregate expression like SUM MAX or MIN

Comment: @Dandersen Even with the two stray variables removed?

Comment: @Magisch Yes :-) Just forgot to remove the variables before posting here. They don't matter :-)

Comment: Your query is not valid. Make the query valid and test again. Someone already gave you a very good comment and you... basically ignored it.

Comment: @JacobH Not really, no? I have not ignored anything.

The query itself works just fine - I need the group by or else it'll return all the data into one, single row instead of multiple rows - Which is what I need.

The problem is, that the joined subquery is way too big for it to handle. The product table is -massive- and I need to find a way around that huge load.

Comment: @Dandersen I doubt that the query works just like this. Using non aggregate fields in aggregate SELECTs is only permitted when they are part of forming the aggregate. How is the query processor supposed to know for instance which of the potentially n `orders.c5_dataset` it should select in your select if you don't tell it?

Comment: It gets all the data just fine.

The query selects all the rows and I print them out in a while loop in PHP.

Comment: Look at the MySQL log and syslog for clues. @Magisch  -- MySQL allows this sort of syntax with non-aggregate columns

Comment: @mustaccio I found out and adressed it in my answer. Still using GROUP BY in that way is still strictly wrong. Any use case where this may be necessary either makes the query produce wrong results or indicate a broken duplicate ridden data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You have problems in both your query and your subquery join.

You're using `GROUP BY` which means your select query is an **aggregate**.

In aggregate queries, you may only use aggregate expressions (like `MAX(field)` or `SUM(field)` or `COUNT(field)`) or fields that *were used in forming the aggregate*.

So if you're GROUPing by `orders_products.products_id`, the only non aggregate field you can use in your select here is `orders_products.products_id`. All other selected fields have to be aggregate functions in your case.

The same goes for your subquery that you're JOINing into.

Futhermore, you have an issue with your data structure, apparently. Lets take a look at your `products` table:

```
SELECT products.products_id, products.product_reseller_account_no, 
products.product_certain_amount, products.product_stock_amount, 
products.product_group_number, products.products_status, 
products.products_competitor_watch, products.manufacturers_id FROM products 
GROUP BY products.products_id
```

There are three possibilities:

- Product ID's aren't the unique identifier of this table and there are 100% duplicate products. This means the database isn't well kept and you should try and trim the duplicates. Or use `DISTINCT` in your select. The `GROUP BY` is therefore unnecessary.
- Product ID's **are** the unique identifier of the table. Then your `GROUP BY` is flat out superflous
- Product ID's aren't the unique identifier and there are duplicate IDs with different data. In that case your query just returns the first for each, making the results potentially (very likely) wrong.

Comment: That makes no sense, though.

I'm selecting the rows and using group by, since if I don't, I get ONE row where all the data has been added together instead of MULTIPLE rows with the data for each specific product.

Comment: @Magisch No sense?? what Magisch says it's rigth, your query will never work in the way it is.

Comment: @nacho But it -does-. I literally have a list of data printed from the query. The only problem is, that it's too slow because of the massive joined products table.

Comment: @Dandersen Then either your database structure is messed up because you have lots of duplicate rows with duplicate data (I assume it takes the first result for each then) and you're violating a design principle or you're getting randomly the first result for each non-aggregate field, which makes the output wrong.

Comment: @Magisch I won't argue against the structure being terrible - It's a legacy (As in really legacy) project. All I can inform you, is the query works just fine, atleast on the website. The only problem is it being way too slow, since it has to join the MASSIVE products-tabel.

Comment: @Dandersen So why do you have to group the products table? Is the product ID not an unique identifier in the products table? If not, what is? Do you just have tons of duplicate entries in that? If there aren't any 100% duplicate entries in the products table, you don't need the group by in the subquery. If there are, you should be getting rid of those first thing. If there are multiple products with different data and the same product id, then your subquery is producing wrong results...

Comment: @Magisch There's duplicates in products and order_products, yes. Same ID, different data. That's the whole reason I need to join it as a subquery, since it'll count some of the fields twice. 


(Sum(orders_products.products_quantity), 0) AS count)

Comment: @Dandersen Then your query is producing wrong results, since it'll pick the first occurence of any non-aggregate field. An example of this effect: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0f44/1/0

Comment: @Magisch Right.. Guess I'll have to rewrite the query from scratch. So what's your final tip here? I don't need to get all of the results, just the product name once (It appears in both products and orders_products with the same ID - Hence the problem) and the counted amount of sold products, which is being counted from the orders_products table.

Comment: @Dandersen My final tip is to learn exactly how grouping works and take a second look at your data structure. try and see if you can find a compound primary key (like combination of ID and department) to uniquely find the product row you want. Also consider indexing the product table properly if not done already. If it's done already, you could try using subqueries to get the product data you need instead of doing a JOIN.

Comment: Asides from that, good luck. Your data structure is all sorts of messed up and I don't envy you having to deal with this.